# Matrix derivative doesn't get evaluated

Tags: matrix, sympy

I'm trying to evaluate the partial derivative of the most general 3D rotation matrix, like this:

```py
phi, psi, theta = sympy.symbols("phi, psi, theta")
RMatrixPhi = sympy.Matrix([[cos(phi), sin(phi), 0],
                           [-sin(phi), cos(phi), 0],
                           [0,          0,       1]])
RMatrixPsi = sympy.Matrix([[cos(psi),  0, sin(psi)],
                           [0,         1,   0     ],
                           [-sin(psi), 0, cos(psi)]])
RMatrixTheta = sympy.Matrix([[1,    0,         0        ],
                             [0,  cos(theta), sin(theta)],
                             [0, -sin(theta), cos(theta)  ]])
RMatrix = RMatrixPhi * RMatrixPsi * RMatrixTheta
D = diff(RMatrix, phi)
```

However,`D` is then a `sympy.Derivative` object, and I cannot get it evaluated,
it's just printed out as `Derivative(Matrix(...))`

The only way I could get it working is by writing

```
sympy.Matrix([sympy.diff(r, phi) for r in RMatrix]).reshape(3,3)
```

but that looks ugly. What's the right way to compute such derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Matrix class has a *method* called `diff` which, according to the documentation ...

> Docstring:
>   Calculate the derivative of each element in the matrix.

So use

```
RMatrix.diff(phi)
```

to perform element-wise derivation.